# Write permission in server folder

Tags: php, web

I would like to create folder in the source code of php web application on server. I tried this code but i can't create a folder inside the application folder. Is it required username and password of server?

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('http://domain.com/tourism/data/new')) {
    if(mkdir('http://domain.com/tourism/data/new', 0777, true))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
        echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: I hope it is, I don't want anybody creating folders on my server as they like. Have you tried ftp, or if you're on the same server: relative path?

Comment: Isn't mkdir() supposed to be given a local path on the server, not a URL?

Comment: @Fluffeh yes and so is file_exists for as far as I know so try to use a relative path

Comment: not sure it's the correct way. My actual requirement is to write files to a folder inside the application from another application.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Desired folder structure relative path
$str = './depth1/depth2/depth3/';

// To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
// to mkdir() must be specified.

if (!mkdir($str, 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}

// ...
?>
```

**Make sure you have permission to create any folder.**

Answer (score 0):

If your script needs to store files, common practice is to designate a dedicated folder for this. This folder will be outside the web-root (not available over http/https) and will have its permissions set in such a way that the webserver can write to it. You can do this with (for example)

```
chgrp https $FOLDER
chmod g+w $FOLDER
```

Consequently, you **cannot** use http:// in your `mkdir`. You should use a filesystem path, for example `/srv/my-script/data`. It is good practice to make this path configurable, for example by putting it in a configuration file.

> […] create folder in the source code of php web application on server.

This is a very bad idea, and might leave you vulnerable to attacks. Attackers may be able to upload their own PHP code.

Answer (score -1):

To do  this, the 'user' executing the script will need write permissions.  This is usually the web-server user (in many linuxes, 'www-data').

This may or may not be advisable.  Most folks advise at least making the location outside the web-root.

Comment: OP uses URLs for arguments, not just paths. This goes a bit further than the usual permissions.